# Intel Wireless WiFi driver for Linux on Dell Inspiron 17 (7746, Early 2015) CentOS 7 Laptop

Tags: linux, drivers, centos, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

So I recently got a new laptop from work, and I'm unable to get the wireless drivers to work in CentOS 7.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Mar 2015 13:47 EDT -0400

Booted last: 13 Mar 2015 13:43 EDT -0400

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
Release:    7.0.1406
Codename:   Core

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Mar 7 13:55:36 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap, vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16, rd.lvm.lv=centos/root, crashkernel=auto, vconsole.keymap=us, rhgb, quiet, LANG=en_US.UTF-8

##### desktop ###########################

GNOME Classic

##### lspci #############################

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5410]

07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5287] (rev 01)

07:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0692]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               13132  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            14000  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
iwlwifi               116602  0 
cfg80211              531303  1 iwlwifi
rfkill                 26772  5 cfg80211,bluetooth,dell_laptop
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19193  4 dell_led,dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifcfg-rh

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     29203CA7DDFAAD012962408
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     6AAC635BDE451B0558DF56A
depends:        rfkill
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### dmesg #############################

[    2.823095] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.823961] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.830609] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.830628] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-11.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.830641] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.830644] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode' failed.
[    2.830702] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-9.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.830704] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7265D-9.ucode' failed.
[    2.830748] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    2.851026] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq failed with error -2
[    2.851032] Bluetooth: hci0 failed to open Intel firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq(-2)
[    2.851333] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
[    2.855263] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Will you please add what you have tried to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
I do not recommend updating CentOS 7 to kernel-ml, as it has a lot of stability issues that can result (specifically, virtualization is not functioning properly).  What I found as a better solution was to look into "Backport" for the Linux kernel.

Visit: https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page
They have a temporary download page, so I don't want to link directly to that in this question since I imagine it'll eventually go away.  Download that releaase:

```
tar xf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.xz
cd backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
sudo make install
```

I rebooted, and everything seems to be working.  No need to update to kernel-ml.

Old answer follows (this also works but you'll no longer be on the CentOS mainline):

So I tried a few things trying to stay "official" such as updating my kernel to the ML release from ELREPO, and installed the additional firmware with linux-firmware package.

What I ended up having to do was visit:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#firmware
Which published the latest firmware updates.

Turns out those firmware headers are actually in the latest kernel-ml headers, they just didn't exist in my /lib/firmware folder.

So I downloaded the Intel® Wireless 7265 tarball from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-23.15.10.0.tgz (there's a table on this page with other latest drivers as well) and just followed the step to copy them into /lib/firmware

```
# cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Rebooted the laptop, and everything worked!